# I am having difficulty accessing the new array return by map(), for objects in an array. I get the error that musicData[i] is not defined

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

- Return a string for each item in the array in the following format:

- ```
  <album-name> by <artist> sold <sales> copies
  ```
- - Store the returned data in a new albumSalesStrings variable.

The code is below;

```
const musicData = [
{ artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
{ artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
{ artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
{ artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
{ artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
{ artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
  name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
{ artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
{ artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
{ artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
{ artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map( function(){
  for(let i = 0; i <= musicData.length; i++){
    console.log( musicData[i].name + " by " + musicData[i].artist + " Sold " + musicData[i].sales + " copies");
  }
});

console.log(albumSalesStrings);
```

Comment: Your usage of map function is completely wrong. Read the documentation here. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this ([refer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```
const musicData = [
{ artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
{ artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
{ artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
{ artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
{ artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
{ artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
  name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
{ artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
{ artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
{ artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
{ artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map((data)=>{
    return (data.name + " by " + data.artist + " Sold " + data.sales + " copies");
});

console.log(albumSalesStrings);
```

The output will be

```
[ '25 by Adele Sold 1731000 copies',
  'Views by Drake Sold 1608000 copies',
  'Lemonade by Beyonce Sold 1554000 copies',
  'Traveller by Chris Stapleton Sold 1085000 copies',
  'A Pentatonix Christmas by Pentatonix Sold 904000 copies',
  'Hamilton: An American Musical by Original Broadway Cast Recording Sold 820000 copies',
  'Blurryface by Twenty One Pilots Sold 738000 copies',
  'The Very Best of Prince by Prince Sold 668000 copies',
  'Anti by Rihanna Sold 603000 copies',
  'Purpose by Justin Bieber Sold 554000 copies' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map((data) => {
return (data.name + " by " + data.artist + " Sold " + data.sales + " copies");}});
```

use string literals instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Use map like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const musicData = [
  { artist: "Adele", name: "25", sales: 1731000 },
  { artist: "Drake", name: "Views", sales: 1608000 },
  { artist: "Beyonce", name: "Lemonade", sales: 1554000 },
  { artist: "Chris Stapleton", name: "Traveller", sales: 1085000 },
  { artist: "Pentatonix", name: "A Pentatonix Christmas", sales: 904000 },
  {
    artist: "Original Broadway Cast Recording",
    name: "Hamilton: An American Musical",
    sales: 820000,
  },
  { artist: "Twenty One Pilots", name: "Blurryface", sales: 738000 },
  { artist: "Prince", name: "The Very Best of Prince", sales: 668000 },
  { artist: "Rihanna", name: "Anti", sales: 603000 },
  { artist: "Justin Bieber", name: "Purpose", sales: 554000 },
];

const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map(function (music) {
  return `${music.name} by ${music.artist} sold ${music.sales} copies`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .map for iteration then why you are using for loop inside it.

just use a .map function and pass parameter inside a .map( IIFE function) like this:

```js
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map((data)=>{
    return (data.name + " by " + data.artist + " Sold " + data.sales + " copies");
});
```

Comment: Ok I get it now.